# click selectively ng-if directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive, angular-ng-if

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="someController as Ctrl">
<div class="clickme" ng-repeat="elems in Ctrl.elem" ng-click="Ctrl.click(elems.title)">
    {{elems.title}}
    <span>click me</span>
    <div id="container">
        <test-Input title="elems.title" data="elems.id" ng-if="Ctrl.myId==" >/test-Input>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
var Elems = [
    {
         title : "First",
         id : 1
    },
    {
         title : "Second",
         id : 2
    },
    {
         title : "Third",
         id : 3
    }
];

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('someController', function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.elem = Elems;
    self.myId = false;
    self.click = function(data){
        self.myId = data;
    };
});

myApp.directive('testInput',function(){
     return {
          restrict: 'E',

          scope: {
              myTitle: '=title',
              myId: '=data'
          },
          template: '<div>{{myTitle}}</div>',
          controller: function($scope) {

          }
      };
});
```

I'm new to angular js. when I click the "click me" div then I want to make ng-if = true result. then show (not ng-show it will renders every elements) the directive. is there any ways to do it angular way?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4L6qbpoy/5/

Comment: Please choose different names for your variables. Maybe it's me, but `elems` being the single, current element with `elem` being the collection confuses me a lot while reading the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
<test-Input title="elems.title" data="elems.id" ng-if="elems.isVisible"></test-Input>
```

and toggle that on click

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58bxg893/)

Comment: thansk!! that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the ng-if evaluate to true within the ng-repeat.  So you need a condition that evaluates the unique value for each object in the array.

```
ng-if="Ctrl.myId==elems.title"
```

To understand, each instance of ng-repeat falls under the controller's scope.  That means the ng-repeated elements are pushed to the boundaries and are only evaluated within your template.  Within those bounds, you have access to a tiny local scope which includes $index, $first, $odd, etc..

You can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat